# How to replace a string in a file only if the line containing it does not also contain a specific string using Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, csv, replace, sed

I would like to replace all instances of `target` with `replace` in the following file.csv using Bash, but only if the line containing it does not also contain the string `skipline`:

file.csv:

```
abc,abc,keepline,target,abc,abc
abc,abc,skipline,target,abc,abc
```

Desired output:

```
abc,abc,keepline,replace,abc,abc
abc,abc,skipline,target,abc,abc
```

I am attempting to use `sed`:

```
sed 's/target/replace' file.csv > newfile.csv
```

How can I include logic to check each line for the string `skipline`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
% sed '/skipline/!s/target/replace/g' input
abc,abc,keepline,replace,abc,abc
abc,abc,skipline,target,abc,abc
```

In `sed` you can specify *where* to substitute: `/foo/` searches for `foo`, `1,5` means *from line 1 to 5*.  A `!` inverts that search.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter lines you need to search and replace

```
$ cat ip.txt 
abc,abc,keepline,target,abc,abc
abc,abc,skipline,target,abc,abc

$ sed '/skipline/! s/target/replace/' ip.txt 
abc,abc,keepline,replace,abc,abc
abc,abc,skipline,target,abc,abc
```

Answer (score 1):

*This will ignore the lines containing `skipline`. And replace target with `replace` keyword.*

```
   awk '!/skipline/ {gsub(/target/,"replace")}1' input
    abc,abc,keepline,replace,abc,abc
    abc,abc,skipline,target,abc,abc
```

*To do the changes in orignal file :*

```
awk '!/skipline/ {gsub(/target/,"replace")}1' input >input.tmp && mv input.tmp input
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Bash and substring replacement:

```
i=abc,abc,keepline,target,abc,abc
if [[ ! $i =~ "skipline" ]] ; then 
  i=${i//target/replace}
fi
echo $i
abc,abc,keepline,replace,abc,abc

i=abc,abc,skipline,target,abc,abc
if [[ ! $i =~ "skipline" ]] ; then 
  i=${i//target/replace}
fi
echo $i
abc,abc,skipline,target,abc,abc
```